# Should we use parameter reference inside a function body when the parameter is supplied as a reference in Rust?

Tags: rust

So I have this simple program that uppercases the string passed,

```
fn main() {
    let string = String::from("test here");
    let result = test(&string);
    println!("{}", &result);
}

fn test(param: &String) -> String {
    let upper = param.to_uppercase();
    return upper;
}
```

Now what I don't understand is if I should use `param` or `&param` inside `test` function body. `string` is already passed as a reference so should I use just `param.to_uppercase()` or does it still make sense to reference the param itself so something like `&param.to_uppercase()`?

Comment: A couple of things: 1. `return upper;` at the end of a function should simply be `upper`. 2. [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219) 3. `&param.to_uppercase()` is parsed as `&(param.to_uppercase())`.

Comment: To extend on what @L.F. said: your test function should be `fn test(param: &str) -> String { param.to_uppercase() }`

Comment: The problem to answer what seems to be the core of the question is that it's not clear why you'd want to take the reference of a reference, or what you imagine would be `&param.to_uppercase()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you're asking about `(&param).to_uppercase()`

You should just use `param`, `&param` is of type `&&String` and that would have no value, (but no cost either if you did this by mistake).